# How do I set the sounds in Apple Push Notification Service? (It's always default?)

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I want to change the sound of what my alert makes, however the following always makes the same sound: (regardless of what I set sound to)

```
 {"aps":{"alert":"Chris \n\r Food is ready. 9","badge":7019,"sound":"Ding"}}
```

Is there something wrong with my JSON?  What value works for sounds?

I'm looking at all the system sounds, and am assuming I'm limited to that.

Comment: What is the audio format of "Ding"?

Comment: What different sounds I can send out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that system sounds aren't available to my application, however [I can import my own](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) as long as it's in one of the following formats

- Linear PCM
- MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
- µLaw
- aLaw

Answer (score 1):

Sorry its only possible for [jailbreak](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2012/02/customize-push-notification-alert-tone-pushtone-jailbreak-tweak.html) devices